# How to switch off desktop pop-ups from Facebook Stories

Tags: 20.04

I keep getting status pop-ups appearing in Ubuntu v. 20.04 at the top of my screen from Facebook Stories of pages I follow

here's an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gybyr.jpg

I don't know how I've activated those but I'd love to know how to switch them off?
Many thanks

Comment: This is a FaceBook issue and has noting to do with Ubuntu. Look at the FaceBook help.

Comment: What browser are you using? You probably enabled Facebook notifications in that browser's settings.